# Is it possible to install android app directly from facebook ad click

Tags: applications, facebook

We have a fb ad for our app but the link click only redirects the user to google play. Is it possible to download the app right away by the time user clicks "Install Now" button at the ad?

If yes, please provide me any brief understandable steps or links.
I've tried searching but the hits are just so confusing and complicated.

Comment: Those steps are in place for a reason. Google would most likely be unhappy with you if you tried to circumvent this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you want user to have an apk installed from playstore. It has to go through play store app. Only other way I can think of is to make user download an apk file of your application from your server (Not a ideal thing to do)